# C ignore dashes on scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to load in two values from a string separated by " - ".
I can't figure out what to put in the scanf to ignore this dash.

Here's a simplified snippet that illustrates the problem:

```
char first[3];
char second[3];

char* str = "foo - bar";
sscanf(str, "%s <what should be here> %s", first, second);

printf("%s %s", first, second);
```

If nothing is placed in the placeholder the program prints "foo -"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell `scanf` to expect a `-`, put a `-` in the format string:

```
sscanf(str, "%s - %s", first, second);
```

Also, make your arrays big enough to hold the characters you expect plus a terminating null character:

```
char first[4];
char second[4];
```

You should also limit `scanf` to the size of the receiving arrays:

```
sscanf(str, "%3s - %3s", first, second);
```

If the `-` might not be present, you need additional code to handle that; a simple `scanf` is insufficient. Similarly, if the strings might be longer than three characters, you need additional code.

Comment: Testing the return value of `sscanf()` seems recommended or the arrays should be initialized as empty strings.

Comment: I tried putting " - " in-between but didn't get the right answer, no wonder when the char arrays are too short. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure it is actually a `'-'` (hyphen) and not an `'–'` (em dash) (and there is a 3rd variant whose name escapes me now)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Hyphen, em dash, en dash, figure dash, horizontal bar, and horizontal scan-line 7, at least.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- I stand corrected. That fancy type-setting stuff is well above my word-processing pay-grade. The en dash was what I was thinking of, and I do know the horizontal bar, but figure dash and horizontal scan-line are new to my vernacular. (a good day -- added to it, now to look them up `:)` [Dashes and hyphens: A comprehensive guide](https://theweek.com/articles/785110/dashes-hyphens-comprehensive-guide)

Comment: To skip all kinds of dashes and punctuation, you can use `sscanf(str, "%3s %*s %3s", first, second);` which will ignore all non whitespace bytes between the words.